# Extract HTML source code linux library

Tags: c++, html, css

i'm using Linux, i need my program to Extract the HTML source code and put it into a string using C++ language , can you give me a library that can do this

Comment: Have you tried using the native C++ file IO?  Try using that and revising your answer; perhaps using a for loop to loop through all the lines of the document and append it to a string?  Please do this soon so that people don't put this question on hold.

Comment: Alright guys, i need to give my c++ program a website (not a HTML file) and the program returns the HTML source code of this website.
EX: i give www.facebook.com i get 
<html>
...
</html>

Comment: @REEDOOX curl leads a good track, for what you're currently asking!

Comment: I need to get the HTML source of a webpage and put it in a string;
if i give www.facebook.com i get in the string : <html>... </html>
in linux i run this command : curl www.facebook.com it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the [easy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string execu(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
std::string result = execu("curl http://www.facebook.com");
```

But this is not considered safe unless you know the string passed is not going to blow anything up.

Comment: i cant make this work , can i know what the curl http://facebook.com;
if it is supposed to get the html source it doesnt :/

Comment: Give `exec()` a different name, it collides with the standard POSIX functions!